# Enabling QoS on IPFire stops all internet traffic, how do I fix it?

Tags: firewall, qos

I have set up QoS on an [IPFire install](http://www.ipfire.org) acting as a router at the gateway to my home LAN. I am using only the default QoS settings, which are meant to function quite well.

When QoS is diabled, the network functions as expected When I turn on QoS ALL traffic between the Red and Green interfaces (internet-facing and inward-facing respectively) stops. Has anyone encountered this problem before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QoS needs correct setting for Up/Downlink speed. After this you have to click on "preset" to calculate the default classes based on you link speeds.
if this settings are wrong it may block the whole traffic.

http://wiki.ipfire.org/en/configuration/services/qos

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried entering those values in both kBit and kByte, same result each time.

Comment: Ok, just tried again and it's working flawlessly. I guess that's what you get for trying to set up new services on your router at 3am!